# Unsaving All Instagram Posts

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Is there really a way of unsaving all of your instagram saved posts with selenium and geckodriver. I have tried with the code below, but it fails every time it gets into the first post. Anybodhy have any suggestions?

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

username = "user"
password = “pass”

options = Options()
# Set the path to the geckodriver executable
geckodriver_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'

options.binary_location = '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'

# Set the geckodriver path in the options
options.add_argument(f"webdriver.gecko.driver={geckodriver_path}")

# Create a Firefox WebDriver with the specified options
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
sleep(2)

# login to the user account
print('logging-in')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name=\"username\"]") \
    .send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name=\"password\"]") \
    .send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type=\"submit\"]") \
    .click()
sleep(8)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+username+"/saved/all-posts/")
sleep(8)  # Wait for page to load

div = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_aagu")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class=\"_aagu\"]") \
    .click()
for i in range(len(div)):
    sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//svg[@class=\"x1lliihq x1n2onr6\"]").click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class=\" _65Bje  coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow\"]").click()
```

I tried the code above and it ran into an error in the for loop. The error is a noSuchElementException which suggests my XPATH is incorrect for the unsave button. I also suspect that my XPATH is also incorrect for the navigation arrow. Can anybody figure out what the proper identifier I should be using could be?

Comment: _it ran into an error in the for loop_: What error did you face?

Comment: Just revised - noSuchElementException. Thanks for your help.